# remove duplicated items with comparing list to another list

Tags: vb.net

```
There are a list1, list2 and list 3.

list 1 contains <british> <electric> <kettle> <and> <bottle> <of> <water>
list 2 contains <british> <electric> <bottle> <water>
the result of list 3 will be <kettle> <and> <of>
```

As you see, duplicated items     has been removed.

Anyone have a code with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ:

```
Dim in1Not2 = list1.Except(list2)
Dim list3 = in1Not2.ToList()
```

If your list2 also can contain items that are not in list1:

```
Dim uniqueIn1Or2 = list1.Except(list2).Concat(list2.Except(list1))
Dim list3 = uniqueIn1Or2.ToList()
```